# Include Sticky Posts with Custom Query

Tags: wp-query, customization

I'm working with Custom Query in WordPress, Basically, I'm showing 4 most recent posts of a category having ID 4
and my **query** is as follows:-

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post' ,
  'orderby' => 'date' ,
  'order' => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'cat'         => '3',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
  
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
```

This is working fine, but here I have an additional requirement. I want to add sticky posts as well i.e Posts will be stick to the top no matters these posts are recent or old, and total posts_per_page should be always 4 including sticky and recent posts.

e.g If there is no sticky post then I'll show 4 most recent posts and no sticky post. But if there is 1 sticky post then there will be 1 sticky post and 3 most recent posts, a total of 4 posts.

What modification should I made in my Query? Thank you.

Comment: A question, Are the sticky posts in the same category? The query should work as you wanted without any further modifications.

Comment: yes in same category

Comment: will this work without any modification? even for sticky posts?

Comment: Yes Just test it, Sticky posts will be shown on top of other posts by default.

Comment: thanks for your precious time and experience

Answer (score 1):

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

$args = array(
  'post_type'           => 'post' ,
  'orderby'             => 'date' ,
  'order'               => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page'      => 4,
  'cat'                 => '3',
  'paged'               => get_query_var('paged'),
  'post__in'            => isset( $sticky[0] ) ? $sticky[0] : array(),
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
  
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
```

The above code will include only the first sticky post and if it does not exist, it will get normal posts.

If you want to show all of the existing sticky posts, then use the following code:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'           => 'post' ,
  'orderby'             => 'date' ,
  'order'               => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page'      => 4,
  'cat'                 => '3',
  'paged'               => get_query_var('paged'),
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => false,
  
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: but there is no limitation for sticky posts, it may have 1 or > 1 sticky posts

Comment: Edited to include detailed answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and help, your first query is returning $q->post_count:0 and the last/2nd query is giving the same result as my above-given query while I have 2 sticky posts

Comment: in case I replace this line in your first query 'post__in'=> $sticky ? $sticky : [], it returns only sticky posts